Enemy prefabs not damaging the Player
The enemy itself damages the player just fine but whenever my enemy spawner spawns an enemy prefab it does not damage the player at it gives this error:
"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Enemy.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D other) (at Assets/Scripts/Enemy/Enemy.cs:72**)"
I tried looking for more forums on this issue but I had no luck. Is there any way this could be fixed?
.......
Here is my code for my enemy script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Unity.IO.LowLevel.Unsafe;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 1;
    Animator animator;
    public float speed = 1;
    private GameObject player;
    public float damage;
    public PlayerHealth playerHealth;
    KillCounter killCounterScript;
    public GameObject [] itemDrops;

    public float Health
    {
        set
        {
            health = value;
            if (health <= 0)
            {
                Defeated();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return health;
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        killCounterScript = GameObject.Find("KillCounterObject").GetComponent<KillCounter>();
        
    }

    public void Defeated()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Defeated");

    }

    public void RemoveEnemy()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        killCounterScript.AddKill();
        ItemDrop();
    }

    private void Swarm()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Swarm();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            if (playerHealth != null)
            {
                playerHealth.health -= damage;
            }
            
        }
    }

    private void ItemDrop()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemDrops.Length; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(itemDrops[i], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}

Here is my code for my playerHealth script:
public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Variables
    public float health;
    public float maxHealth;
    public Image healthBar;
    public GameManager gameManager;
    private bool isDead;
    
    void Start()
    {
        health = maxHealth;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        healthBar.fillAmount = Mathf.Clamp(health / maxHealth, 0, 1);
        if (health <= 0 && !isDead)
        {
            isDead = true;
            gameManager.gameOver();
            gameObject.SetActive(false);

        }
    }
}


suggesting that playerHealth is likely line 72 (always nice when people point out the line) but it has not been set, as it is not mentioned elsewhere .. that seems likely

@BugFinder where would I need to mention it? (btw sorry for not pointing out the playerhealth line)

well, you didnt include all the relevant code, so from what we cam see playerHealth isnt even a variable, but it must be.  You clearly didnt set it, or somehow destroyed it

This question is similar to: What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The error states that a value in the OnTriggerEnter2D function is null. This basically means that a reference to a component or another script is yet to be set. The error indicates that the request happens in line 72. Please look at that line again in your code and double-check for any value being null. I would guess that the playerHealth variable (a reference to a script?) is null, and so there is no health property because there is no instance.
Here is the OnTriggerEnter2D function revisited with null checks to identify potential issues:
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{ 
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) 
    { 
        if (playerHealth != null)
        {
            playerHealth.health -= damage;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Player Health ia null and cannot be set! Initialise Player health variable before trying to change it!");
        }
    } 
}

Edit: Indeed, you never assigned the playerHealth variable. Here is the start method updated to initialize playerHealth:
private void Start() 
{ 
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>(); 

    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    //you can replace this with a direct reference via the inspector (make it public or serializable)

    killCounterScript = GameObject.Find("KillCounterObject").GetComponent<KillCounter>(); 
    //you can replace this with killCounterScript = FindObjectOfType<KillCounter>(); for better performance and you can delete the tag

    playerHealth = FindObjectOfType<PlayerHealth>(); 
    //same as before
}

As a comment pointed out, you already have a TakeDamage() function, so why not use it?
Instead of writing playerhealth.health -= 50; you can write playerHealth.TakeDamage(50); which is both easier to read and easier to modify if you take damage in a lot of different scripts.

Thank you for your help. I put in the code you recommended and the errors don't appear but the prefabs are still not damaging the player.

Because playerHealth is null..

@MichaelFadare can you edit your question toinclude the whole script so we can see if you setup playerHealth correctly? Do you have any code in your Start or Awake to setup references?

@CheckerT I have included my playerHealth script in my question and the only thing I have in my start is a reference to my maxHealth

The whole enemy script aswell because te null rerence error is happening there

@CheckerT updated the post

You already have TakeDamage function in PlayerHealth..use playerHealth.TakeDamage(damage) instead of playerHealth.health -= damage;
